# Change different self.view.backgroundColor Images When app Oriented to Landscape and Portrait

Tags: ios, objective-c, orientation, autolayout

```
- (void) didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)fromInterfaceOrientation{
    if ((fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (fromInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)) {
        self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgImage.png"]];

    }
    else
    {
        self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgImage1.png"]];
    }
}
```

I used above code to set `self.view.backgroundColor` Image when device is oriented to either Landscape or Portrait. The Images changing correctly.

Problem:

1. When i try to rotate the device the images is not changing quickly, I mean it taking 2 to 3 seconds to change the image.
2. How to set `self.view.backgroundColor` image for the first time depending upon Landscape or Portrait.

Comment: Making a guess: try to use -(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration instead of didRotate and let me know if it worked :)

Comment: Use my All three methods and you got solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try the following:

Answer 1: Do it in `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:duration:` method of your VC. This method is the animation method that is called when interface orientation changes and would give a smooth transition between background images.

Answer 2: Set your `self.view.backgroundColor` with required image, in `viewWillAppear:animated:` method taking `self.interfaceOrientation` into account, which reflects the current interface orientation of the VC.

Ideally you can create a method like this:

```
-(void)setBackgroundForInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation {
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(orientation)) {
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-iphone3-landscape"]];
    }
    else {
        self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg-iphone3"]];
    }
}
```

Now call this method from either place:

```
-(void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    [self setBackgroundForInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation];
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];

    [self setBackgroundForInterfaceOrientation:self.interfaceOrientation];
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: `willRotateToInterfaceOrientation` method is better than what is used.thanks for help.

Comment: @user1997951 glad that it helped. If you have received your solution please mark that as answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    UIDeviceOrientation currentOrientation = [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation;

    if (currentOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft
        ||  currentOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
        [imageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"backgroundImage.png"]];
    }
    else
    {
        [imageview setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Portrait-backgroundImage.png"]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use it

```
     -(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
       {

          [self willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:[UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarOrientation duration:1.0];

        }


     -(void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
                                     duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
      {

        if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
          {
              self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgImage1.png"]];
          }
        else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || (toInterfaceOrientation==UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown))
          {
             self.view.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bgImage.png"]];
          }
       }
```